# Best approach to scrape dynamic website(built using react) using python scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have been trying to scrape this website [Link](https://www.nykaafashion.com/) using scrapy and scrapy-splash. This website as far as i know developed in react. `response.xpath` always returns empty list with any classname. Please suggest me a way to approach scraping of this react website. I have setup splash using this [link](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash) and able to scrape some other websites in the same project but unable to scrape this react made website. Code for the spider is written below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class NykaaFashionbrandsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nykaa_fashionbrands'

    start_urls = ["https://www.nykaafashion.com/"]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 'fashion_brands.csv'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                                endpoint='render.html',
                                args={'wait': 3},
                                )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.xpath('//*[@class="br-inner"]/ul/li/text()').extract())
        # I am trying to get the list items
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of code ?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to **scrape** all products or product in a particular category you have you use API url like this one:

```
https://www.nykaafashion.com/rest/appapi/V2/categories/products?categoryId=6151&PageSize=12&sort=popularity&currentPage=2&filter_format=v2
```

This piece of response:

```
"products": [
            {
                "sku": "CTWK0648",
                "imageUrl": "https://adn-static1.nykaa.com/nykdesignstudio-images/pub/media/catalog/product/3/8/3884c_1.jpg?rnd=20200526195200",
                "isOutOfStock": 0,
                "subTitle": "Black Embellished Sandals",
                "title": "Catwalk",
                "price": 1995,
                "tag": {},
                "offerCount": 0,
                "categoryId": [
                    "102",
                    "3528",
                    "3522",
                    "2",
                    "6151",
                    "6557"
                ],
                "discount": 55,
                "offers": null,
                "discountedPrice": 899,
                "actionUrl": "/catwalk-black-embellished-sandals-3/p/537684",
                "aspectRatio": 0.75,
                "sizeVariation": [
                    {
                        "id": "537678",
                        "title": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "537679",
                        "title": "5"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "537680",
                        "title": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "537681",
                        "title": "7"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "configurable",
                "id": "537684"
            },
```

`Splash` not needed for this website

Comment: Thank you for providing the rest API but I wanted to list out the brands along with the links(in the "Brand " dropdown). And this is just one example. I m seeking the approach on how to scrape react websites because nowdays many startups and companies have shifted to react framework. Also may I know the approach to fetch such api endpoints i.e how to find them if unable to scrape. Thank you for taking out the time.

Comment: open website in chrome >  ```ctrl + shift + i``` navigate to ```Network``` tab > find required API call. In my answer, I just provided one API call. for brands, it will be different or maybe one some parameters changed

Comment: different pages will have different API call. but for this websites, if you need ```brands``` they located inside JS ```window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = JSON.parse```. so you can collect this JSON and it will contain all brands with names, links etc. If you need product/category information - it will we an API call I guess

Comment: Ok I got some idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should definitely give [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) a try. I recently tested scraping OpenSea, and it worked perfectly.

install it by running

```bash
pip install cloudscraper
```

to scrape the data do:

```py
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(browser="chrome")
url = "https://www.nykaafashion.com/"
scraped_status = scraper.get(url) #get status code
scraped = scraper.get(url).text #get the data
```